# How do I change permissions on an external hard drive in Arch Linux?

Tags: permissions, removable-storage

Permissions to my portable hard drive on Arch is read-only and it seems I can't change it- when I change it from the GUI it takes no effect. So, how can I change it through the terminal?

Is there some config file relating to accessing hard drives? I'm asking because there's no problem such problem with SD cards. I also can't seem to 'Safely Remove Harddrive' although no processes are going on.

Comment: What filesystem is on your external drive?

Comment: please include the line of the mounted drive from `cat /proc/mounts` also this is unlikely to have anything at all to do with "arch" specifically

Comment: @pdo- sorry for the really late reply(i was AFK for a really long time) but its NTFS

Answer (score 3):

First, in order to work with NTFS (a proprietary file system) you need to install ntfs-3g:

```
# pacman -S ntfs-3g
```

There is a page on the the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ntfs) that will step you through configuration options, such as automounting and user access...